# jQuery adding Attribute to a link generated on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navigation witch works with dropdown, but the parent has to be clickable as well.

Thats no problem at all for desktop users, but it has to be responsive as well.
That brings the problem that mobile devices don't have hover. I got some Javascript that handles that. I have to add an attribute `aria-haspopup=true` to the links that have a child link.

The problem is, the link's are loaded by dnn and I can't change anything on that module. So I have to add it afterwards.

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$("#menu ul:has('li')").each(function () {
  $("#menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-250 li:has('a')").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("aria-haspopup", "true");
  }
});
```

Comment: The code to add that attribute should be working fine. It's more likely that the problem is that you're adding the attribute *after* the library that requires it has been initialised. You need to make sure that the code that needs the `aria` attribute runs *after* you have added it to the DOM.

Comment: Also note that you don't need any of the `each()` calls here. Just `$("#menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-250 li:has('a')").attr('aria-haspopup', 'true')` will add the attribute on all selected elements.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan i made sure it runs after it. It doesn't add the attribute to any link that has been generated.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? I can see you're missing a `)` in the code above, but I assumed that was just a mistake made when transposing the question

Comment: No error and no warning in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it...

```
$(document).ready(function($){
$("ul.submenu").each(function(index){

     $(this).parent("li").children(":first").attr('aria-haspopup', 'true');    
    }) 
});
```